# @Html.EditorFor percentage display and save

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have a table column

```
CurrentFeeUplift    decimal(7, 4)     -- > 0.0010
```

EF definition

```
 [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:P2}")]
    public Nullable<decimal> CurrentFeeUplift { get; set; }
```

using razor i am trying to display value stored in it as percentage --> 0.10 %

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CurrentFeeUplift, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control ClientInfo" } })
```

after editing save doesn't work because the submit returns '0.10 %' when it should return '0.0010'. so model ModelState.IsValid is false

Comment: It works the same for % as it does for $ in the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot POST "10%" string using Nullable field. You should change your CurrentFeeUplift property to string and then use it like that in the action method:

```
model.CurrentFeeUplift = ((int)(model.CurrentFeeUplift.Replace('%','')) / 100.0).ToString();
```

before you save it to the database.

OR

If you cannot change your model, you should prepare javascript code to remove "%" sign before POST call, but it's a workaround.

Comment: submit returns '0.10 %' with the percentage sign , so model ModelState.IsValid is false

Comment: if ModelState.IsValid is false then model.CurrentFeeUplift is NULL